# Return Json from MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I'm trying to return Json data from an MVC Application.  I used Fiddler and FireBug to troubleshoot this and the Json data seems to be ok, but for some reason the data still doesn't display.  This is my code:

```
public class CalendarController : Controller
{

public JsonResult ReturnCalendarEvents()
        {


            var model = _service.EventList("JackV", "10/1/2011", "10/8/2011");
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }

}
```

Site.Master

```
 $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          async: false,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          url: "/Calendar/ReturnCalendarEvents",
          data: "{'UserName':'" + UserName + "','starTime':'" + start.format("isoDateTime") + "','endTime':'" + end.format("isoDateTime") + "'}",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (result) {
            //Logic goes here
                },
                                error: function (e) { alert("An Error Occured" + e); }
                            });
```

So even though in Fiddler I see the actual Json data being returned, in the Site.Master file, this goes straight to the error.  The error returned is [Object object].  Not too helpful.  I debugged my application and there are no errors anywhere before the data is being returned as Json.  Unless the data is not true Json somehow but it sure looks like it.

The weird thing is that the ajax function runs, then goes straight to error, then I step into the Visual Studio code for my controller, then it goes back to this ajax function but this time it does error out, it goes to the success code.  Somewhere along the way, it stops debugging in FireBug and I'm not sure why the data is not being returned.

Can anybody think of anything that might help me figure this out?  Thank you.

---

Solution:   After I looked at everyone's comments i realized that this line was wrong:

```
  var schedules = (eval(result.d));
```

This was part of my Success logic that I didn't include in the post.  In FireBug result showed data, but .d was null.  This worked just fine in a web application but it doesn't like the .d in the MVC app.  I changed the code to this and now it works fine.  I still don't know why that function gets hit twice, with the first one erroring out but the 2nd one retrieving the data.  I will look into it more.

```
 var schedules = (eval(result));
```

Comment: How does the JSON returned from the server look like? Also may I ask why did you set the `async` flag to `false`? Also you seem to be sending some JSON data in the request to the controller action but the action you showed doesn't seem to take any argument at all. Another question: what if the Username contains a single quote?

Comment: start a debug session and put a breakpoint on your controller action. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using all the arguments to the error callback property for the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method: xhr, textStatus, and errorThrown and inspecting them to see what the actual error is.  Note that the xhr object has properties that you could output (i.e., it's an object which is why you're getting that), but textStatus is probably more informative.

```
 $.ajax({
     ...
     error: function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                alert("Error - " + textStatus );
     }
 });
```

Comment: So would the code be something like this: function (e) { alert("An Error Occured" + e + e.event + e.statusText + e.errorThrown); }.  I'm not too familiar with javascript.  Thank you.

Comment: @MikeB55 - I've updated with a sample and will add a link to the API docs -- look for the specification of the error callback.

Comment: @MikeB55: No, just change the `error` function signature in your example to what it looks like in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Further to what tvanfossen says. Try validating your Json in http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ However, I would expect the MVC framework to throw an error if it couldn't serialize as JSON.

Comment: Yes, i used the Json validation and it's valid Json.  Thanks. At least I know the Json is valid.